# Proof convergence of improper integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm having problems with this integral
$\int_1^\infty \frac{(\ln x)^n}{x^p} \, dx $  where $p > 1.$ I tried to use comparison test for improper integrals using that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{p-k}} \, dx$ with $0<k<p-1$ converges.
This led me to this limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\ln x)^n}{x^k}$ and I can't continue, I thought in use L'Hopital but I am not sure it works

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\ln (x)=\frac 1 r\ln (x^{r}) \leq \frac 1 r x^{r}$. Choose $r \in (0, \frac {p-1} n)$ so that $p-nr >1$.